# How can we format (grouping) email from SQL query?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2015

I have code that I am running a SQL query to string variables and writing them to Outlook. The code works fine but I am having a bit of trouble when there is more than one result. Each result runs together in the email...

**Present Result:**

> Thank you for your order!
>
> Order Number 20016721Order Number 20016721
>        Part Number: NRE0000Part Number: PWR1812
>       Description: NRE ChargeDescription: High Power USB Charger
>       Customer Part Number:1234Customer Part Number:1234
>       Customer Revision:A Customer Revision: A
>       Expected Ship Date: 9/22/2017Expected Ship Date: 9/22/2017
>
> Regards,

**What I want:**

> Thank you for your order!
>
> Order Number 20016721
>       Part Number: NRE0000
>       Description: NRE Charge
>       Customer Part Number: 1234
>       Customer Revision: A
>       Expected
>   Ship Date: 9/22/2017
>
> Order Number 20016721
>       Part Number: PWR1812
>       Description: High
>   Power USB Charger
>      Customer Part Number:1234
>      Customer Revision: A
>   Expected Ship Date: 9/28/2017
>
> Regards,

Here Is my Code:

```
 string ord = "";
        string pn = "";
        string des = "";
        string cpn = "";
        string rev = "";
        string esd = "";
        string qty = "";
        string eml = "";
        string sbj = "";

        string str = @"Data Source=my source;Initial Catalog=table;Integrated Security=True";
        SqlConnection scn;
        SqlDataAdapter da;
        DataSet ds;


        myTableAdapter.SO(_A_TWIDataSet.SalesOrders);


        scn = new SqlConnection(str);
        da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT DISTINCT DATEADD (dd, DATEDIFF(dd,0,ShipDate),0) AS ShipDate,RTRIM(SalesOrder) AS [Sales Order], RTRIM(PartNum) AS [Part Number]," +
            "RTRIM(Description) AS Description,RTRIM(DueQty) AS Quantity,RTRIM(CustPartNum) AS[Customer Part No], RTRIM(CustPo) AS[Customer PO], " +
                                 "RTRIM(CustRev) AS[Customer Rev], RTRIM(email) AS [Email] " +
                                 "FROM SalesOrders WHERE Ack <> 'Y'AND SalesOrder =" + MyGlobals.ord, scn);
        ds = new DataSet();da.Fill(ds, "SalesOrders");
        foreach(DataRow Row in ds.Tables["SalesOrders"].Rows)
        {
            ord = ord + "Order Number "+ Row["Sales Order"];
            pn = pn + "Part Number: " + Row["Part Number"];
            des = des + "Description: " + Row["Description"];
            cpn = cpn + "Customer Part Number: " + Row["Customer Part No"];
            rev = rev + "Customer Revision: " + Row["Customer Rev"];
            DateTime dte = DateTime.Now;               
            esd = esd + "Expected Ship Date: " + dte.ToShortDateString();
            qty = qty + "Quantity: " + Row["Quantity"];
            eml = eml +  Row["Email"];
            sbj = sbj + "Order Acknowledgement for your PO " + Row["Customer PO"];
        }


        try 
        {

            //Must add Outlook Reference Object Library

            Outlook.Application _app = new Outlook.Application();
            Outlook.MailItem mail = (Outlook.MailItem)_app.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);

            mail.To = eml;
            mail.BCC = ";CustomerService@touchstn.com";
            mail.Subject = sbj;
            mail.BodyFormat = Outlook.OlBodyFormat.olFormatHTML;
            mail.HTMLBody = "<HTML><BODY>";

            mail.HTMLBody += "Thank you for your order!" + "<br />" + "<br />" + ord + "<br />" + pn +
                              "<br />" + des + "<br />" + cpn + "<br />" + rev + "<br />" + esd + "<br />"
                               + "<br />"+ "Regards," 



            mail.Display(true);
           // mail.Send();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
```

Thanks in advance

**Update: Results form using the suggested code below (almost there!!)**

> Thank you for your order!
>    Order Number 20016721Part Number:
>   NRE0000Description: NRE ChargeCustomer Part Number: Customer Revision:
>   Expected Ship Date: 9/22/2017Quantity: 1Order Number 20016721Part
>   Number: PWR1812Description: High Power USB ChargerCustomer Part
>   Number: Customer Revision: Expected Ship Date: 9/22/2017Quantity: 400
>
> Regards

,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do is create a one string with the order details in it with line breaks a proper places.

Consider following code.

```
using System.Text;
[...]

var orderListBody = new StringBuilder();
var eml = string.Empty;
var sbj = string.Empty;
foreach (DataRow Row in ds.Tables["SalesOrders"].Rows)
{
  orderListBody.Append("Order Number " + Row["Sales Order"] + "<br />");
  orderListBody.Append("Part Number: " + Row["Part Number"] + "<br />");
  orderListBody.Append("Description: " + Row["Description"] + "<br />");
  orderListBody.Append("Customer Part Number: " + Row["Customer Part No"] + "<br />");
  orderListBody.Append("Customer Revision: " + Row["Customer Rev"] + "<br />");
  DateTime dte = DateTime.Now;
  orderListBody.Append("Expected Ship Date: " + dte.ToShortDateString() + "<br />");
  orderListBody.Append("Quantity: " + Row["Quantity"] + "<br />");
  orderListBody.Append("<br />"); //Adding extra line break between two orders.
  eml = Row["Email"];
  sbj = "Order Acknowledgement for your PO " + Row["Customer PO"] + "<br/>";
}
```

And HTMLBody should be set as following.

```
mail.To = eml;
mail.BCC = ";CustomerService@touchstn.com";
mail.Subject = sbj;
mail.BodyFormat = Outlook.OlBodyFormat.olFormatHTML;
mail.HTMLBody = "<HTML><BODY>";

mail.HTMLBody += "Thank you for your order!" + "<br />" + orderListBody.ToString() + "<br />"+ "Regards," ;
```

This should resolve your issue.

Comment: Much better code - but almost there Here are my results:    Thank you for your order!
Order Number 20016721Part Number: NRE0000Description: NRE ChargeCustomer Part Number: Customer Revision: Expected Ship Date: 9/22/2017Quantity: 1Order Number 20016721Part Number: PWR1812Description: High Power USB ChargerCustomer Part Number: Customer Revision: Expected Ship Date: 9/22/2017Quantity: 400
Regards,    sorry - this didn't come out a clear as I hoped - I will post my results above in the original question

Comment: How different is the result if this code than what is expected ?

Comment: the items are grouped in separate blocks instead of together (for example, my code had Order Number Order Number) whereas your code suggestion will separate them in each loop

Comment: So you want to group the order items under the order number? As per the expected output mention in the question the order number is being repeated and tried to replicate the same. Can you update your question with what exact output you want in the email? Are there any chances that there are multiple order numbers in the data table with multiple order items for each of them? If yes then how you want the orders to be displayed in the email?

Comment: sorry - I must be confusing things. the original question has the output I want. under the heading "What I want" Please see the update to the question as to the results of your code suggestion - it is close, just not quite formatted (with line breaks) as needed. hope this clarifies things

Comment: Where do you display the message at the moment ? In a Mail client ?

Comment: I got it. It's wrong `br ` tag. It should be `<br />`. I am not able to edit my answer. Not sure why. But if you correct the br tag you should get expected output .

Comment: thank you @Chetan Ranpariya - your updated solution worked well !

Answer (score -1):

What you are trying to do is simply appending multiple results in single variable in a loop. What I can gather from your example is that you have two different orders that need to be printed in the html body of outlook. For that you need to maintain different variables for each order (Not advisable). You can create a class of order specifics (such as ord, pn, des, cpn, rev, esd) and then use the class objects to store the values for each order specifics. (differtiate the orders on the basis of part numbers. (Take care of the code in for loop to be precise).

EDIT as requested:

Just an example below. Take care of the syntax wherever needed. (I typed this on my way home )

//your class specifics will go something like this..

[class for order specifics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SSrD8.jpg)

//your actual class where your main logic is there
[your actual class where your main logic is there](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XiAij.jpg)

This way may not be the most efficient on handling huge records but the code is cleaner. Hope this helps. Enjoy!

Comment: thank you @ni3 - I neglected to clarify this in my question but there could be any multiple of orders (not restricted to two). Sorry for not being clear on that

Comment: @in3 - can you give me an example of the class of order specifics?

Comment: @AlanRobertson pls check. I have edited my answer. So, at the time of constructing the outlook html body, iterate through all the class objects to print all the values. Hope it helps you. Should you have any queries, pls write back. Cheers!

Comment: @LarsTech my apologies, as I typed this on my way home. I ll definitely take care of this next time. Enjoy!

Comment: Next time?  How about this time?

Comment: @LarsTech maybe after monday coz I m out of ofc on vacation right now. dont have my laptop with me. Remind me though. Thanks in Advance!!